# making old website responsive

Tags: css, joomla, web, media-queries

I have an old website and it's not responsive,I want to make it responsive, but the media queries I've used won't work because there is a mobile.css that is destroying everything. What can I use to make it responsive or I need somehow to disable that mobile.css? Website was made in joomla.

Comment: Have you tried updating it with bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: No,I actually never used it before. I'll try now. Thank you so much!

Comment: That is the most simple one to learn lots of videos on you tube for help also. I have tried foundation 4 and 5 but prefer bootstrap

Comment: Joomla is responsive by default since it is build with the assumption that you are using Bootstrap. But are you on a very old version of Joomla?

Comment: Yes,it is an old version that's why it won't work

Answer (score 0):

You would need to convert the site into a grid system based on percentages.

I would suggest converting the site into a css framework with a grid system,
it would probably take less time then trying to "Frankenstein" the code.

Here are the links to get started that I would suggest to start,

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

[Zurb Foundations](http://foundation.zurb.com/index.html)